# Php format array for wathcfolder

Tags: php, arrays, directory, watch

How do I format an array which holds the folders of a folder (Watchfolder) in a basic html table.

This is the basic function

```
function dirToArray($dir) {

    $result = array();

    $cdir = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
        {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
            {
                $result[$value] = $this->dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
            }
            else
            {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I call it like this;

```
$watchFolderPath = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mop\\Rp\\';
$watchFolder     = $this->dirToArray($watchFolderPath);
```

if I print_r this it gives me the correct values, in this case folders with its subfolder.
Looks like this:

```
array:6 [▼
  345 => array:2 [▶]
  789 => array:2 [▶]
  "folder1" => array:2 [▶]
  "folder2" => array:2 [▶]
  "folder3" => array:2 [▶]
  "folder4" => []
]
```

I do not know how to format this properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `echo` HTML tags mixed with the array results:

```
echo "<table>";


for ($row = 0; $row < count($watchFolder); $row++)
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $watchFolder[$row] . "</td>";

    for ($col = 0; $col < 2; $col++) {
        echo "<td>" . $watchFolder[$row][$col] . "</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Arrange the table as you see fit - `<tr>` tags are rows, `<td>` tags are data items.

**Edit:**

To handle folders with no subfolder, perhaps try something similar to this inside the loop.

```
    if is_array($watchFolder[$row]) {
        for ($col = 0; $col < 2; $col++) {
            echo "<td>" . $watchFolder[$row][$col] . "</td>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get an Undefined offset: 0 at the second for loop

Comment: Maybe because the final element in the array has no subarray. Could try adding a check, see edit of original comment.